# Tools for plotting behavior of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software, graphing-functions

I have several ODEs describing the behavior of dividing particles (e.g., [How to model multi-step cell differentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84155/how-to-model-multi-step-cell-differentiation)). I would like to plot these ODEs based on changing values of p over time.  I would appreciate any advice on what graphics program would be suitable for this task.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can perform this sort of thing in Mathematica. If you have Mathematica, check the documentation center for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'll second Matlab but make specific metion to the Matlab toolkits [pplane](http://math.rice.edu/~dfield/dfpp.html)
and [Matcont](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/MATCONT).

Matcont is particularly useful for investigating bifurcations, which seems to be what you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either MATLAB or Python for that. Both have strong visualization capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a lok at [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/), a free open-source mathematics software.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a flexible way of doing this, à la:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func(p, t):
  """Takes a vector p representing the current state and the time t"""
  pdot = 0.2*[0]**0.75
  return [pdot]

t    = np.linspace(0, 100, 200)              #Return state at these time points
init = [2]                                   #Initial conditions
z    = scipy.integrate.odeint(func, init, t) #Integrate the ODE
z    = z.T[0]                                #Transpose and extract state

plt.plot(t,z)
plt.show()
```